# Websocket consecutive send() on different routes

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

As title says:
I'm trying to set up websocket connection like:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/admin');
```

`/admin` will return list of sessions.
Then for each session I need to send more data but to `/admin/${sessionX}`

Is this even possible without making new ws connection?
websocket.send() fun doesn't explaint it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: No its not. Are you sure you need a websocket? Sounds like a regular REST api would work.

Comment: yeah, indeed, the backend that I connect to, has REST but new versions require newer libmicrohttpd and it will take time till I can upgrate to newer OS release...
It is probably not good practice, but since I have ~20 session, how heavy would it be to make one new ws connection per session to retrieve data I need/